# Lombok extension methods: Prevalence/priority?

Tags: java, aop, lombok, aspect, method-signature

First off: I absolutely LOVE Project Lombok. Awesome tool! There's so many excellent aspects to this 'compile time' library.

Loving the `@ExtensionMethod`s, I have already hit this 'feature' a few times, so now it's time for me to ask this question:

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
@UtilityClass
public class AObject {
    static public String message(final Object pObject) {
        return "AObject = " + (pObject != null);
    }
}
@UtilityClass
public class AString {
    static public String message(final String pObject) {
        return "AString = " + (pObject != null);
    }
}
@ExtensionMethod({ AObject.class, AString.class })
public class Run_Object_String {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\nRun_Object_String.main()");
        final String s = "Bier!";
        final Object o = new Object();

        System.out.println("Testing s: " + s.message());
        System.out.println("Testing o: " + o.message());
        System.out.println("Testing s: " + s.message());
    }
}
@ExtensionMethod({ AString.class, AObject.class })
public class Run_String_Object {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\nRun_String_Object.main()");
        final String s = "Bier!";
        final Object o = new Object();

        System.out.println("Testing s: " + s.message());
        System.out.println("Testing o: " + o.message());
        System.out.println("Testing s: " + s.message());
    }
}
public class ClassPrevalenceTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Run_Object_String.main(args);
        Run_String_Object.main(args);
    }
}
```

With the output:

```
Run_Object_String.main()
Testing s: AObject = true
Testing o: AObject = true
Testing s: AObject = true

Run_String_Object.main()
Testing s: AString = true
Testing o: AObject = true
Testing s: AString = true
```

- Why is this?
- Why is the `message(String)` not called in the first example, even though it has a better method signature fit than `message(Object)`?
- Why is `@ExtensionMethod` dependent on sequence of the arguments?

Here's what I blindly assume:

- when parsing for ExtensionMethods, Lombok will process annotation values from left to right
- - For `Run_Object_String` that means: first `AObject`, then `AString`
- - For `Run_String_Object` that means: first `AString`, then `AObject`
- Object-String: When patching `AObject` into class `Run_Object_String`, the `message(Object)` method will be added. And when patching in `AString` with the `message(String)` method, it will not be added.
  Presumably because the `message(Object)` also matches a call to `message(String)`, so `message(String)` will not be added.
- String-Object: When patching `AString` into class `Run_String_Object`, the `message(String)` method will be added.
  When patching in `AObject` class with `message(Object)`, the old and present `message(String)` method will NOT accept the call `message(Object)`, thus the method `message(Object)` will be added.

So, apart from taking great care of what order I add the `@UtilityClass` references, are there any other solutions to this?

- Can the Lombok preprocessor be extended and made more sensible when adding in extension methods?
- Do you guys have any suggestions regarding this, or an explanation of what is really happening (as opposed to my assumptions)

Comment: @rzwitserloot  I cannot post questions on https://groups.google.com/g/project-lombok, so I'm posting here.

Comment: @roelspilker I cannot post questions on https://groups.google.com/g/project-lombok, so I'm posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fascinating use of Lombok I wasn't aware of. The best place I think you could delve to find your answers is the source itself since the docs on this experimental work seems pretty light, understandably.

Take a look on git here: [HandleExtensionMethod](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/5120abe4741c78d19d7e65404f407cfe57074a47/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleExtensionMethod.java).

I am guessing based on the logic that the area that's effectively "fitting" the right method from the annotation is as below..

Instead of trying for a "best" fit, it seems to be aiming for a "first" fit.

That is, it appears to iterate over `List<Extension> extensions`. Since it's a Java list, we assume ordering is preserved in the order the extensions were specified in the original annotation.

It appears to simply work in order of the list and `return` as soon as something matches the right method and type shape.

```
Types types = Types.instance(annotationNode.getContext());
        for (Extension extension : extensions) {
            TypeSymbol extensionProvider = extension.extensionProvider;
            if (surroundingTypeSymbol == extensionProvider) continue;
            for (MethodSymbol extensionMethod : extension.extensionMethods) {
                if (!methodName.equals(extensionMethod.name.toString())) continue;
                Type extensionMethodType = extensionMethod.type;
                if (!MethodType.class.isInstance(extensionMethodType) && !ForAll.class.isInstance(extensionMethodType)) continue;
                Type firstArgType = types.erasure(extensionMethodType.asMethodType().argtypes.get(0));
                if (!types.isAssignable(receiverType, firstArgType)) continue;
                methodCall.args = methodCall.args.prepend(receiver);
                methodCall.meth = chainDotsString(annotationNode, extensionProvider.toString() + "." + methodName);
                recursiveSetGeneratedBy(methodCall.meth, methodCallNode);
                return;
            }
        }
```

You can look at the rest of the code for other insight as there doesn't seem to be too much there (i.e. number of lines) to look at, though admittedly it's an impressive enough a feat to do in that space.

Comment: Oh this is awesome! Thanx a lot for directly linking the source! I had a go at the source code a while back, in search for the annotation processors, but only found two and they were not what I was looking for. This is gold!

Comment: Thanks for asking. Your sample code tests and reasoning were enlightening and I feel like I learned a cool new Lombok trick today. I'd be happy to take an accept-answer for the kudos points, but if you want to leave the bounty open for more attention, that makes sense too. Maybe even more people would chime in!

Comment: There's a time restriction on assigning the bounty. When I wrote my comment I still had 8 hours to go before I could assign it. But gimme some more time, maybe even one of the founders of Lombok chime in.

Comment: No worries at all. It would be good if you could find someone with that deeper insight! Good luck.